# Posting formatted string on postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, postman

I have a site that lets people answer coding problems. I want to save the questions that I ask them in a mongodb database, and the answers they send in as well. In testing the routes I have set up in my express application, I cannot figure out how to send this formatted text in the request to successfully save it to the database. I would like to keep this format as I use a few npm packages on my react front end to parse this data to make code snippets.

Here is my mongoose model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const codingProblemSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
    },
    question: {
      type: String,
      default: true,
    },
    problem: {
      type: String,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

codingProblemSchema.virtual('answers', {
  ref: 'CodingAnswer',
  foreignField: 'codingProblem',
  localField: '_id',
});

const CodingProblem = mongoose.model('CodingProblem', codingProblemSchema);

export default CodingProblem;
```

Here is an example of the data I would try and send to my backend to create a new coding problem:

```
const codeProblem = {
    date: 'April 15th, 2021',
    question: `You are writing the logic for a vending machine to return change to
  its customers. This function, called <code>makeChange</code>, takes
  two parameters (<code>price</code> and <code>payment</code>). Based on
  the <code>price</code> and <code>payment</code>, return how many
  dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies the customer will
  receive back.`,
    problem: `function makeChange(price, payment) { 
    // your logic here
}

    makeChange(1, 5) // expected output -> [4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    // price was $1 and customer paid $5. Change back is [4 dollars, 0 quarters, 0 dimes, 0 nickels, 0 pennies]
    
    makeChange(1.55, 20) // expected output -> [18, 1, 2, 0, 0]
    // price was $1.55 and customer paid $20. Change back is [18 dollars, 1 quarter, 2 dimes, 0 nickels, 0 pennies]
    
    makeChange(3.67, 100) // expected output -> [96, 1, 0, 1, 3]
    // price was $3.67 and customer paid $100. Change back is [96 dollars, 1 quarter, 0 dimes, 1 nickels, 3 pennies]`,
  };
```

Here is a screenshot of my postman POST request failing:

[image: postman data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "date": "April 15th, 2021",
  "question": "You are writing the logic for a vending machine to return change to\n  its customers. This function, called <code>makeChange</code>, takes\n  two parameters (<code>price</code> and <code>payment</code>). Based on\n  the <code>price</code> and <code>payment</code>, return how many\n  dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies the customer will\n  receive back.",
  "problem": "function makeChange(price, payment) { \n    // your logic here\n}\n\n    makeChange(1, 5) // expected output -> [4, 0, 0, 0, 0]\n    // price was $1 and customer paid $5. Change back is [4 dollars, 0 quarters, 0 dimes, 0 nickels, 0 pennies]\n    \n    makeChange(1.55, 20) // expected output -> [18, 1, 2, 0, 0]\n    // price was $1.55 and customer paid $20. Change back is [18 dollars, 1 quarter, 2 dimes, 0 nickels, 0 pennies]\n    \n    makeChange(3.67, 100) // expected output -> [96, 1, 0, 1, 3]\n    // price was $3.67 and customer paid $100. Change back is [96 dollars, 1 quarter, 0 dimes, 1 nickels, 3 pennies]"
}
```

JSON supports only double quotes , you cannot enclose property and value with single or string literal

else you can just stringify and parse the content you already have :

```
     JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(codeProblem ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the new line in postman and your problem will be solved. I attach the image below. Select row and JSON type over there.
[image]

Comment: That works for the question. But the actual code portion I need to maintain the spacing for the functions.